# How can I redirect DNS requests to a different DNS server with iptables

Tags: networking, dns, iptables

I am trying to get my living room TV to use ExpressVPN's DNS servers so that I can expand my options.. The only thing is my "smart" TV does not let me change the DNS settings it just uses what the router gives it, which in this case is the IP address to my small server running pihole.

Is it possible to redirect the DNS requests from my TV to ExpressVPN's DNS servers?

I tried using https://askubuntu.com/questions/592042/iptables-redirect-dns-queries but it did not seem to work.

This is what I ran: `sudo iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING-p tcp -s 192.168.86.167 --dport 53 -j DNAT --to-destination 85.203.37.1:53`

But when I check on ExpressVPN it says it is not configured to use their DNS.. Any suggestions?

Comment: `PREROUTING`, not `OUTPUT`, as you are redirecting requests from others. Also `-p udp` in addition `-p tcp` (practically `-p udp` might already do though). And I assume you are already doing `SNAT`/`MASQUERADE` at the tun.

Comment: @TomYan Can you elaborate on the SNAT/MASQUERADE at the tun

Comment: A rule in `nat`/`POSTROUTING` that makes sure traffics go to the VPN server will have your VPN IP as source IP instead of your LAN IP (which makes no sense outside your LAN).

Comment: it seems to be working since I added `sudo iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 192.168.86.167 -j MASQUERADE` it says that it is configured correctly now on the site